# parse text file and remove commas inside double quotes in java

Tags: java

I have a `txt` file and it has lines like below:

`"abc","bkc", "New York", "NY","cool guy"`

I am looking to replace comma with semicolon(;) that don't have a comma inside double quotes:

Desired Output:

`"abc";"bkc"; "New York"; "NY";"cool guy"`

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you want to replace every occurrence of `","` with `";"`, correct? I mean every appearance of three characters where first character is a double quote, second character is a comma and third character is another double quote.

Comment: String fileContent = "\"abc\",\"bkc\", \"New, York\", \"NY\",\"cool guy\"";<br>
String replacorPattern = "[^(\\\\)]\\\" *, *\\\"";<br>
String result = fileContent.replaceAll(replacorPattern, "\";\"");<br>
System.out.println(result);<br>

Comment: yes Abra i want to do same

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .toCharArray() method on that string to generate a array and then iterate trough it.

```
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i<chars.length-1; i++){
    if(chars[i]==',') chars[i] = ';'
}
```

Or is the problem with reading the file?

Comment: *replace comma with; that don't have a comma inside double quotes* - how does your question address this?